# Selected for the/in first place for a scholarship

Tags: phrases, expressions

I got a scholarship some years ago and was selected in first place of the list. I don't now  what is the right way of writing this on the CV:

i) selected for the first place nationally

ii) selected in first place nationally

Maybe both are wrong,

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you were selected ***in** first place*. That implies confusingly that you were already in it when selected. I prefer *for first place*, which implies that you were chosen to be put in first place.

There is no single correct way of saying this; there are many correct alternatives; and there are many ways of saying it incorrectly! Here are a few alternatives:

*Placed first in the XXX Scholarship rankings.*

*Top national holder of the XXX Scholarship.*

*Lead national holder of the XXX Scholarship.*

Comment: I'd make it *national lead holder* rather than *lead national holder*, to avoid the implication that there are national and non-national holders.